# How to upload file on web page with Power Automate

Tags: automation, upload, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

Could somebody tell me please, how can I upload file with [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/) through file dialog? I need to upload a picture to: https://www.instapainting.com/assets

*File dialog*

[image: Image. An OS generated file selection dialog box, showing multiple thumbnail images]

I can't find any related action in Power Automate "Browser Automation" and "File" or "Folder" sections, and also don't see answer in the net. So, if somebody knows how can I do it, please let me know about it.

Comment: It looks like it is aimed more at SharePoint, but perhaps [this tutorial](https://www.expiscornovus.com/2021/03/31/select-a-file-in-a-dialog-box/) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I hope this will help me